# Using Coulomb's law with atomic nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, coulombs-law

In my text book they stated:

> As an example, the wave function of an electron that is in position $2p$ in a hydrogen atom given by:
> $$
> \varPhi(r,\theta,\varphi)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}a_0^{3/2}}\frac{r}{a_0} e^\frac{-r}{2a_0}\cos\theta
> $$
> If we want to calculate the average electrostatic force of the electron (Assume that the atomic nucleus is at rest) then we need to use the Coulomb's law:
> $$
> \vec{F}=-\frac{kq_e^2}{r^2}\hat{r}
> $$

I don't understand why the Coulomb's law is between two electrons and not between the electron and proton inside the atomic nucleus. did they meant the proton but because $|q_e|=|q_p|$ then they just wrote $q_e$?

Comment: Yes, because the expression for the Coulomb force explicitly contains the minus sign

Answer (score 0):

$$q_e$$ just means elementary charge, not charge of an electron.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: the difference is that the coulomb force was calculated with the elementary charge , not the charge of an electron, so it is the law for an e around a charge qe, here the charge of the proton,

Comment: Actually, $q_e = -e$. $e$ is the electronic charge and is equal to the charge of a proton, and negative of the electron.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your textbook skipped a step in the explanation.

In a hydrogen atom the Coulomb force between proton ($p$)
and electron ($e$) is
$$\vec{F}=\frac{kq_pq_e}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

Now the proton charge is the opposite
of the electron charge:
$$q_p=-q_e$$

Therefore you can rewrite the Coulomb force between proton
and electron as
$$\vec{F}=-\frac{kq_e^2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$